# what is the best grid to use in angular 4+ having searching, sorting, pagenation functionality, and easy to code and integrate

Tags: angular, datagridview, angular-material

Best grid to use in angular 4+ having searching, sorting, pagenation functionality, and easy to code and integrate.

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://www.google.com)?

Answer (score -1):

You can do some research and also trial and error to find which one's best to use.

I have tried multiple options including `Angular material, bootstrap, Ngprime.`

I found Ngprime easy to integrate and use. As it provides different types of grid which includes, filtering, sorting, selection, editing, CRUD operations and many more.

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table

Comment: @Dowvoters: I understand if you are having a bad day, but there is no point in downvoting a correct answer :) Happy coding.

Comment: it was probably downvoted as you answered a really bad question, its off topic to ask for resources so you shouldnt answer said questions

Comment: Well. Deciding something as good or bad is about opinions and perceptions. Isn't it ! There are thousands of dumb questions asked by beginners on SO but I believe our job here is provide help and correct directions to them :)

Comment: yes, correct them by pointing out not to ask off topic questions, not by hand feeding users who dont do research